Jenkins npm start command
I am running a pipeline on jenkins, when I use the command "npm start" I am able to access my nodejs app via port 3000, however, my pipeline does not progress to other stages. I have tried to use commands such as "npm start &" which progresses my pipeline to other stages, however it does not seem to run my app as I cannot access it from the browser.
